# Autocomplete(auto fill) multiple field by selecting one field

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to make auto fill related field by selecting from one field. like..select company name & auto fill its description, number. I dont know jquery I look few example but did not find or understand.

```
if (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']){
$company = array();
try {
    $statC = $db->prepare('SELECT CompanyID, CompanyName, CompanyNumber, CompanyDescription FROM Company');
    $statC->execute(array('type' => '%'.$_GET['type'].'%'));

    while($row = $statC->fetch()) {
        $company[] =  $row['CompanyName'];
        $company[] = $row['CompanyID'];
        $company[] = $row['CompanyNumber'];
        $company[] = $row['CompanyDescription'];
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
echo json_encode($company);
}
```

My jquery autocomplete works but show all result in one input field

```
 $(function() {

    //autocomplete Day
    $(".companyid").autocomplete({
        source: "company.php",
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

Should i make separate array in php? like

```
$comName = array();
$comID = array();
$comDes = array();
$comNum = array();
```

Comment: You can do it with select event of autocomplete. On select event fetch related data using ajax and assign it to form elements.

Answer (score 0):

jquery UI Autocomplete is used for showing suggestions while typing like google do. You can

```
var type = 'Your type goes here';
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json?type=" + type, function( data ) {
    //data will be a json object of following structure
    //{"CompanyName":"CompanyName", "CompanyID":"CompanyID", "CompanyNumber":"CompanyNumber", "CompanyDescription":"CompanyDescription"}
    //
})
```